# Putting a breaker panel in detached home office half bath

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm building a home office and have a question about placement of the main breaker panel. Ideally it will go in a half bath (toilet and sink only) in the corner of the structure. Reading elsewhere I see conflicting information on whether NEC allows a panel in a bathroom.

**Before you answer**, here are the pertinent facts:

- This is an entirely detached outbuilding, 30 yards from the main house, supplied by an entirely separate utility meter.
- This building will be 100% office space, "business use only" per the IRS. It does not in any way fit the definition of a "dwelling unit" and should therefore not be subject to those particular restrictions. It is comprised of a small entry area, one big office room, plus the corner half bath (what I would call a washroom).
- The main service disconnect will be on the building exterior, opposite side of the wall where I hope to put the breaker panel.
- We live in the boonies, outside any local ordinances or inspection requirements. I'm interested in adhering to code wherever possible, of course, but solely for safety and good practice considerations. I'm OK with varying from the more arcane, arbitrary specs when it makes sense.
- I want to avoid putting the panel in the main office room because it will interfere with usability of that space (shelving/cabinets and clear space requirements).

Thoughts?